# How does main app know when an sub app has been installed in ios?

Tags: ios

How does an app know when an app by the same developer has been installed in iOS?

Comment: @Veeranhaneyu have you check my answer ? or are you facing some other issue ?

Comment: Actually problem is My app having some ads , when i click on that ads it's redirect to app store and installed.How to know that app installed throw my app?

Comment: ok fine than use my code to check if app is not installed it will return `NO` and based on that you can redirect to iTunes or if `YES` you can open that app by `openURL` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by `openURL` method which will help to check app installed in your device or not.

**Objective-C:**

```
 UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

 NSLog(@"App installed %d",[application canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"AppName://"]]);

 [application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"AppName://Test"] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
      NSLog(@"Open result %d",success);
 }];
```

**Swift:**

```
let appURL = "AppName://extra_param_for_launchscreen"

let URL = NSURL.init(string: appURL)

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(URL) {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(URL)
}
```

by `canOpenURL` you can check app installed or not.

> Note : for iOS 9.0 and grater you need to add
>   `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your info.plist file with your app
>   schema name to white list your app and get installed app status or open app.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, we can use concept of URL Schemes to find out whether the app we are looking for is installed or not.(By using **canOpenURL** method). But recently, apple removed this functionality to know whether app installed or not from iOS9 due to privacy policy of apple. So, now you cannot find out the sub app is installed or not in any manner due to security reasons.

Following links might be helpful to you:

[canOpenURL to query url schemes](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/)

[Privacy and URL Schemes in iOS9](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/privacy-and-url-schemes-in-ios-9--cms-26550)

Comment: You can still query for url schemes, you just need to declare the schemes you want to be able to query for in your info.plist and there is a limit to how many URL schemes you can kist

Comment: Yes, I agree on that. You need to white list the URL schemes first